# Loop through paragraphs, create individual objects

Tags: regex, powershell, switch-statement

I need to take the below output from a `dirquota au l` command on a 2008 R2 server, iterate through each line, add the relevant data for each auto quota path to its own unique object, then add all of the objects to an array. See example below:

```
Auto Apply Quota Path:  E:\Dir\SubDir
Share Path:             \\SERVER\SubDir
                        \\SERVER\E\Dir\SubDir
                        \\SERVER\Dir\SubDir
Source Template:        Template (Matches template)
Limit:                  500.00 MB (Hard)
Thresholds:
   Warning ( 80%):      Event Log
   Limit (100%):        Event Log

Auto Apply Quota Path:  E:\Dir\SubDir
Share Path:             \\SERVER\SubDir
                        \\SERVER\E\Dir\SubDir
                        \\SERVER\Dir\SubDir
Source Template:        Template (Matches template)
Limit:                  500.00 MB (Hard)
Thresholds:
   Warning ( 80%):      Event Log
   Limit (100%):        Event Log

Auto Apply Quota Path:  E:\Dir\SubDir
Share Path:             \\SERVER\SubDir
                        \\SERVER\E\Dir\SubDir
                        \\SERVER\Dir\SubDir
Source Template:        Template (Matches template)
Limit:                  500.00 MB (Hard)
Thresholds:
   Warning ( 80%):      Event Log
   Limit (100%):        Event Log

Auto Apply Quota Path:  E:\Dir\SubDir
Share Path:             \\SERVER\SubDir
                        \\SERVER\E\Dir\SubDir
                        \\SERVER\Dir\SubDir
Source Template:        Template (Matches template)
Limit:                  500.00 MB (Hard)
Thresholds:
   Warning ( 80%):      Event Log
   Limit (100%):        Event Log

Auto Apply Quota Path:  E:\Dir\SubDir
Share Path:             \\SERVER\E\Dir\SubDir
                        \\SERVER\SubDir
                        \\SERVER\Dir\SubDir
Source Template:        Template (Matches template)
Limit:                  500.00 MB (Hard)
Thresholds:
   Warning ( 80%):      Event Log
   Limit (100%):        Event Log
```

For example, take any auto quota, and I want to isolate the "Auto Apply Quota Path:" portion, which I know I can do with RegEx and `Select-String`, add that to an object under the "Name" property, then isolate the "E:\Dir\Subdir" portion and add that to the same object under the "Value" property. I then want to collect the data from Source Template and Limit, adding those to the same object. Then, once it gets to the blank line, add the object just created to an array, empty the object variable, and begin iterating through the next auto quota section, going through the same process.

Here's the code I'm working with so far:

```
$AutoQuota = @()
$AutoQuota = dirquota au l
$AutoQuota = $AutoQuota[2..$AutoQuota.Count]
$obj = New-Object PSObject
$objArr = @()

$AutoQuota | % {
    switch -regex ($_) {
        "^Auto.*" {
            $Name  = $_ | Select-String -Pattern "^Auto*: " |
                     %{$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value}
            $Value = $_ | Select-String -Pattern "\w:*" |
                     %{$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value}
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Name -Value $Value
        }
        "^\s*$" {
            $objArr += $obj
            $obj = @()
        }
    }
}
```

There will be more to the `switch` statement obviously, I just want to get the first line to work as expected, then I'll add the rest. If there's an easier/better way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the command output to a single string and split that string at two consecutive linebreaks (Windows encodes linebreaks as CR-LF, so you need `\r\n` for each linebreak)

```bsh
(dirquota au l | Out-String) -split '\r\n\r\n'
```

Then filter by a regular expression that groups the values you want to extract from the substrings, and construct the objects directly from the matches:

```bsh
$re = 'Auto Apply Quota Path:\s+(.*)[\s\S]*?' +
      'Source Template:\s+(.*)\s+' +
      'Limit:\s+(.*)'

... | Where-Object { $_ -match $re } | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    Path     = $matches[1]
    Template = $matches[2]
    Limit    = $matches[3]
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this puts me on the right track. Only issue is I'm only getting a result from the first block of data. I'm piping in `(dirquota au l | Out-String) -split '\n\n'` to the `Where-Object`, is that correct?

Comment: @AshHousewares Yes. The linebreaks may be encoded as CR-LF, though, so check `-split '\r\n\r\n'` as well. Also check if the blank lines are preserved in the captured command output and that the blank lines don't contain other whitespace.

Comment: OK so the `-split \n\n` is not actually splitting the string, as the output only contains 1 element, so it matches the first group and that's it. If I split on a single new line, I get 53 elements, as expected because there are 53 lines of output. I suspect splitting on 2 new lines isn't working for some reason, maybe due to the format of the string output?

Comment: Yes you are correct about the CR-LF format. I just tested and got 7 elements in my output, so that gives me exactly what I need. Thank you! I just learned a little more.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
$template=@"
{Groupement*:Auto Apply Quota Path:  {QuotaPath:c:\Tmp\tmp2}
Share Path:             {SharePaths:\\Server\
                        Yy2
                        Zz3}
Source Template:        {SourceTemplate:Template xxx (Matches template)}
Limit:                  {Limit:600.00 MB (Hard)}
Thresholds:
   Warning ( 80%):      {TWarning:Event0 Log0}
   Limit (100%):        {LWarning:Event0 Log0}}

{Groupement*:Auto Apply Quota Path:  {QuotaPath:Zxx}
Share Path:             {SharePaths:Xx3
                        Yy4
                        Zz5}
Source Template:        {SourceTemplate:Template (Matches template)}
Limit:                  {Limit:500.00 MB}
Thresholds:
   Warning (100%):      {TWarning:Event1 Log1}
   Limit (100%):        {LWarning:Event1 Log1}}
"@

$result=$AutoQuota | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template
$result.groupement | select QuotaPath, SharePaths, SourceTemplate, Limit, TWarning, LWarning
```